# How to call a method from a class using a button?

Tags: javascript, class, button, methods

I am getting a reference error "addCharacter not defined". Not sure what I need to change?
The goal is that when a user types in a name and age, an hits submit, it saves the character to an array. Here is what I have so far:

```
<input id="inputName" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="John">
<input id="inputAge" type="text" placeholder="Age" value="20">
<button onclick="addCharacter()">Submit</button>
```

```
//Create Class
class Character {
  name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
  age = document.getElementById("inputAge").value;

  //Method
  addCharacter = () => {
    let characterList = [];
    characterList.push(this.name, this.age);
    console.log(characterList);
  };
}

//Store instance in variable
const myCharacter = new Character();

//Execute
myCharacter.addCharacter();
```

https://codepen.io/lacheporter/pen/jOVQmqp?editors=1111

Comment: It's a class, so try `addCharacter() { ...` Also, you are calling `onclick="addCharacter()"` but nowhere you define this function. It is a method inside a class

Comment: You can't call `addCharacter` from the onclick handler.  The method isn't global, and requires an instance of the Character class.

Comment: Looking at the down votes I am assuming this was a bad question somehow?  I am a little new to programming and definitely classes. You answered my question however, so I will post my answer after I rewrite it. I was just calling a function that didn't exist thinking that it did exist in the class, as a method. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @lache You're welcome, I was happy to be of assistance to you.

Answer (score 0):

I just made it a function that does what I want, so I hope it helps others.
I was creating a class for something that could be done with a simple function. It was mostly for learning purposes. Not sure I see the point in classes?

```
<input id="inputName" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="John">
<input id="inputAge" type="text" placeholder="Age" value="20">
<button onclick="addCharacter()">Submit</button>
```

```
let characterList = [];


function addCharacter(){

 let name = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
 let age = document.getElementById("inputAge").value;

characterList.push(name, age);
console.log(characterList);
 
}
```

Comment: Classes have benefits for the organization and compartmentalization of code.  The class isn't useful in this particular instance.